# Not passing hidden tests: checking if a string can be rearranged to form a palindrome

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to complete this question using a Stack:
Given a string, find out if its characters can be rearranged to form a palindrome.

Example

For inputString = "aabb", the output should be
solution(inputString) = true.

We can rearrange "aabb" to make "abba", which is a palindrome.

However, my code isn't passing 2 of the hidden tests and I am unsure as to why.
Here is my code:

```
boolean solution(String inputString) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        Character curr = inputString.charAt(i);
        if (stack.contains(curr) == false) {
            stack.push(curr);
        }
        else {
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    if ((stack.size() == 0) || (stack.size() == 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**False positive**:

Consider the string `"cabcc"`, which cannot be rearranged to form a palindrome. Your code will first push `c` then push `a` then push `b` then remove `b` (since it is a stack and it found `c` in `cab`) then remove `a` (since it found `c` in `ca`).

Since the stack has a length of 1, your program will output that `cabcc` can be rearranged into a palindrome when it cannot.

**False negative**

Consider the string `"acac"`, which can be rearranged to form a palindrome (`acca` for instance). Your code will first push `a` then push `c` then remove `c` (since it is a stack and it found `a` in `ac`) then push `c`. Resulting in a stack containing `ac`.

Since the stack has a length of 2, your program will output that `acac` cannot be rearranged into a palindrome when it can.

**How to fix**

Do not use a stack. I suggest you use a map (check out hashmaps).